# Php join multiple query results laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join

I have two `queries` that I need to run to obtain, a list of contracts and a list of sales, due to the fact that there is a duplicate contract for each customer I have written a  query that will return customer_id and the date of their final contract while joining on our products table to filter for certain products. another query returns a list of sales for a given area by connecting to a couple of tables as well is their anyway after calling these queries I could join them using `php` .

```
    $contracts = DB::table('contracts as c').....
    $leads= DB::table('contracts as l')..
```

so after creating these two collections that both have the column customer_id, i want to join them using PHP if these where both tables in my database this would be a simple left_join, however, I can't figure out a way to do it with the output of the quarry .... thanks in advance for all the help. I have been doing some research and think i need to map somehow

```
   $leads = $leads->map(function ($item, $key) {
    $single_lead = $contract->where('l.customer_id',$item->spp.customer_id);
    return collect($item)->merge($single_lead);
```

something like this but this is not working and I'm stuck so I should be going through each item in leads and then merge it with the contract information that has the same customer_id

Answer (score 1):

Your question wasn't very clear but giving you a hint to do left join,
You can do it as:

```
$query = DB::table('contracts')->leftJoin('customer','customer.id','=','contracts.customer_id')->get()
```

You can see it in the  [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins)

Comment: i dont want to join the tables i want to join the query results

Comment: I'm not sure about your exact case but its a bad idea to do it in PHP as if there's a huge data and you are using loops then it can cause a very time consuming task or probably can results into Timeout. So you should find a way to query in such a way to get your required data. If you have customer_id column in both of your tables then you also can join 3 tables including your customer table and other two with customer_id columns.

Comment: in that case, do you know if there is a way , while i am doing left_join based on cutomer_id to indicate , that it should the latest observation for that specific customer_id on the right .... we keep our contracts in one place and there for all of the same customers old contract information is lokated there so when i join i end up with the first contracts informtaion not the lasts